# Перадать логику из контейнера в компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Есть компонент **Таблица**, который я хочу отображать в компоненте-контейнере. В таблицу я передаю данные и иконки (редактировать, удалить). Иконки добавляются в каждую запись в таблице.

```
ID -------- NAME  --------
1  -------- Vasya --------  edite, delete 
2  -------- Alex  --------  edite, delete
```

Необходимо как-то связать каждую иконку с определенным ID в таблице. При нажатии кнопки уходит запрос на сервер. Такая логика не должна, по идее, быть в компоненте. Но если я в контейнере создам колбэк на onClick по иконке, то он будет срабатывать для всех записей. Как решаются подобного рода задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у вас в есть функции `editUser(userId)` и `deleteUser(userId)`, которые выполняют соответствующие запросы на сервер. Тогда вот как можно описать компонент UserRow, представляющий строку таблицы.

```
const handleEditClick = userId => {
  editUser(userId)
}

const handleDeleteClick = userId => {
  deleteUser(userId)
}



const UserRow = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.user.id}</td>
    <td>{props.user.name}</td>
    <td onClick={handleEditClick.bind(null, props.user.id)}>edit</td>
    <td onClick={handleDeleteClick.bind(null, props.user.id)}>delete</td>
  </tr>
);
```

соответственно использовать его можно так:

```
const UserTable = props => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {props.users.map(user => <UserRow user={user} />)}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)
```

вот работающий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/kbpaf9zh/

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае Вы можете создать в своем контейнере такую функцию:

```
onSelectID(ID) {
  return (event) => {
    const user = this.userList[ID]; 
    // операции с конкретным user
  }
}
```

В Render контейнера вы пишете что-то типа такого:

```
render() {
  const userList = this.userList.map( val => {
    <UserComponent
      key={val.ID}
      user={val} 
      onClick={this.onSelectID(val.ID)} // <- обработчик только для конкретного ID
    />
  }

  return (userList);

}
```